# Can't find Gtk header file

Tags: gtk, pkg-config

I've searched this forum and the internet, but still can't find a solution.

I want to compile a simple Gtk example program. I use the recommended pkg-config in the compile instruction. But pkg-config says:

> Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps
>   you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc' to the
>   PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'gtk+-3.0' found

I tried:

```
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev
```

and also tried a general distribution-update via APT and many other things with APT.

What can I do?

[Edit: I use Xubuntu 18.04 x86-64.]

Edit 2:

The output of **"apt-cache policy libgtk-3-dev"** is:

```
libgtk-3-dev:
  Installiert:           3.22.30-1ubuntu4
  Installationskandidat: 3.22.30-1ubuntu4
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.22.30-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Greetings
Peter

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libgtk-3-dev` to the question.